# Bind model to function call return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am working on an angular project and I use a directive to create an isolated scope. The directive looks like this:

```
var directive = module.directive('question', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'question.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            quiz: '=quiz'
        },
        link: function (scope, attr, element) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.quiz;
            },
            function (oldVal, newVal) {
                scope.currentQuestion = scope.quiz;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

For I do not want to bind to a property (or field) in my Controller, I created a function and call the directive this way:

```
<question quiz="quiz.getCurrentQuestion()">... (transcluding stuff)</question>
```

Please note that `quiz` is my Controller using the `as`-Syntax.

The way I process the directive is working, but I don't like to create a two-way-binding ( to an R-value?).

Now I tried to just pass the function using `&`-binding but this just turns out odd results in the `link`-function and breaks everything.

Can I use the function-binding using `&` and somehow call the function (in my template or in the `link`-function) to get the result I need to make it work like two-way-binding?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

The return value of the `getCurrentQuestion`-function is an object which looks like

`{
  questionNumber: 1, 
  answers: [], 
  getQuestionText() : function(...),
  ...
 }`

So nothing to special, I hope...

**EDIT 2**

When I use

```
...
scope: {
    quiz: '&quiz'
}
```

then in the `$watch`-function I get

`function(locals) { return parentGet(scope, locals); }` for `scope.quiz`

And if I call the function like `scope.quiz()` I get `undefined` as result.

Comment: Can you give an example of the response of quiz.getCurrentQuestion() ?

Comment: could you create a plunkr?

Comment: @PankajParkar I'm sorry, no I must not, it is production code and I am asking only for curiosity...

Comment: There is an opening quote missing (templateUrl) option, please fix it (I cannot edit it, the edits this short are not allowed).

Comment: @plamut Thank you for the hint, I changed the path before I copied the code here, in my source code, there is an '

Comment: As for your question - the `&`-binding should be the right way to do it. What exactly is the "odd  result" in the `link` function you said you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find any way to watch a function in scope binding. However, there are other solutions. If you want single way binding you can use '@', but that means that you would have to parse the JSON in the watch ( [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/mpqazyat/1/)):

```
var directive = module.directive('question', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'question.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            quiz: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, attr, element) {
            scope.$watch('quiz', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                scope.currentQuestion = angular.fromJson(newVal);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It works, but if you have a high rate of updates, the overhead can be annoying. What I would do, is use a service that holds all the questions, and both controller and directive can talk to. When the current question is changed, the controller should pass to the directive only the id of the new question (using simple @ bind), and the directive would query the service for the question.

Comment: +1 for the idea! I did not figure that myself to have another service provide the questions. I will give it a try!